# "At this point" sentence format

Tags: sentence, formatting

this is my first question on the English Stack Exchange. I was thinking to myself when I thought of these sentences:

1. At this point in time, he would have eaten dinner.
2. At this point in time, he would have had eaten dinner .
3. At this point in time, he has eaten dinner.
4. At this point in time, he had eaten dinner.
5. At this point in time, he eats dinner.

I've been questioning my English skills for a while now, so that's why I'm asking. What are the differences between each sentence, and what would that imply?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried all on Grammarly, all were marked right.

Comment: Five questions is four too many. But #1 is not graceful.

Comment: _At this point in time_ simply indicates the exact moment that something happens. However, sentences 1 - 4 are not idiomatic because we don't say _He has dinner eaten_. You need to change them to _He has eaten [his] dinner_ (and similarly with the other tenses).

Comment: 3 and 4 are identical. What does "At this point in time" mean that _now_ doesn't? Are these inferences about his habits or observed facts? Whose inferences or whose observations? The speaker's or someone else's?

Comment: #2 “has had eaten” is wrong. This is really a question about verb tenses, isn’t it?

Comment: #2 "He would have had eaten dinner" is wrong. Did you mean "He would have had dinner" for that one? Are you asking about "to have dinner" or about "to eat dinner"?